# Regression Test Coverage

Tags: community, unit-test, app-development

Is it required to do a full/complete regression test on all customized development objects or functionalities for a Salesforce release? Is development on Salesforce platform modular i.e. an object or business function can be changed and tested without changing and testing other objects or functionalities?

Answer (score 3):

If your question is: When SFDC releases a new version (e.g. Winter 15), do you have to retest your org?

The answer would in general be NO - that is what SFDC offers as a benefit of a cloud platform. Furthermore, SFDC releases are backward compatible.  Your VF and Apex customizations are stamped with an API version and SFDC will retain those versions' functionality with each new release.

Now, from time to time SFDC will withdraw support for a feature but that will only be for classes/pages upgraded explicitly by you to the to-be-released version.

And, from time to time, SFDC will announce changes in application functionality that are not API specific - these would be critical maintenance alerts - and these you do need to review as your org may be depending on a particular behavior that is changing. And in these circumstances, you get months to evaluate the change before accepting it (or if you wait too long, the change goes into effect automatically)

But, if you have a particularly mission critical SFDC org, when each SFDC release comes out, it is available in beta sandboxes where you can rerun your regression tests or do user testing just to make sure nothing has broken.  But, beware, the beta sandboxes may have bugs, especially in the first few weeks so what you discover can be reported up the ladder to SFDC to fix before the release goes into PROD (this can be time wasting as other orgs and appexchange vendors may be discovering the issues long before you).

You should also know that SFDC will regularly do small maintenance releases to fix bugs that may affect only a small subset of customers.  These patches are expected to be seamless to all end user orgs and you'd have to be super paranoid to rerun your regression tests when they arise.

This is not to dissuade you from running daily regression tests against your PROD org just to make sure some point and click config change doesn't break expected behavior (or at least point out where your tests/sandboxes may need upgrading).  My orgs have never done this (we use fullcopy sandboxes for that purpose) but others may do so.

Comment: Fine example of a recent break: we have a web service function that worked okay for two years. One day recently, it stopped working, which was traced down to a mismatched parameter name in the function call. Neither the Javascript nor the Apex Code had been modified the entire time (we have this code in a repository as proof). Occasionally regression testing code is a good idea.